# Change achievement icons on Profile Summary to match their respective websites

Tags: feature-request, badges, profile-page, icons

When looking at the Accounts tab, the icons shown for achivements all belong to the specific website you are looking at, not the Stack Exchange website shown to the left. For example, here is what I see looking at the "Accounts" tab from Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange:

[image: Accounts and badges picture]

To visualize the suggested change: all the websites shown in the list (besides Android Enthusiasts) would show a circle, not the Android robot's head.

I feel that this should be changed because it would provide a better representation of the sub-website in the "Accounts" list.